# CKEditor and jQuery serialize() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, ckeditor

I'm having trouble with the jQuery serialize() function.

In context, I'm opening a form and checking for changes made to it, so when the form loads, I serialze the data and assign it to a global variable:

```
form_data.edit_initial = $('#edit-job-form').serialize();
```

That works fine.

Then when I come to click a button to leave the form, it performs this check:

```
var start = form_data.edit_initial;
var end = $('#edit-job-form').serialize();

if (start == end) 
{ 
    // Do button action 
}
else
{ 
    // Open confirm dialogue 
}
```

ANYWAY. Both serialize() functions work, but the second one has converted apostrophes etc into a series of numbers and percentage symbols (Which i can safely assume is some code for apostrophe).

Any ideas why? It means even when no changes are made, the dialogue opens and moans that the form's been changed without saving.

**Help!**

Here's some sample data.

I am using a CKEditor instance.

Part of the first result:

```
&edit_time_digital=60&edit_desc=%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%09They'd+like+the+share+their+site+incase+people+want+to+see+their+entire+collection+of+furnature.%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%09The+site+needs+the+following%3A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cul%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Home+page%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Standard+pages%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Galleries+(By+category)%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Contact+page%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09News+listings%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ful%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%09It+should+be+a+very+simple+generator+build.%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A&edit_status=active`
```

and the second:

```
&edit_time_digital=60&edit_desc=%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%09They%26%2339%3Bd+like+the+share+their+site+incase+people+want+to+see+their+entire+collection+of+furnature.%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%09The+site+needs+the+following%3A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cul%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Home+page%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Standard+pages%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Galleries+(By+category)%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09Contact+page%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%09%3Cli%3E%0D%0A%09%09News+listings%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ful%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%09It+should+be+a+very+simple+generator+build.%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A&edit_status=active
```

Comment: Why don't you just compare each form control's current value to its default value? If they're different, it has been changed.

Comment: Do you mean `serialize()` returns two different values depending on when you call it, even if you don't change any control value in the form?

Comment: Frédéric - that's exactly what I mean, yes.

Comment: @Alex, can you post the two values returned by `serialize()`? It might help us understand why they're different.

Comment: @frederic - I've added some sample data to the original question

Comment: @Alex, the `'` character is replaced by its numeric HTML entity representation (`&#39;`) in the second result. That looks like a browser artifact to me, which one are you using? Can you reproduce the problem on another browser?

Comment: @Alex there's a lot you're not telling us about. Those encoded values include lots of HTML markup.  What exactly does your "form" look like?  What are the input elements like?  Why is there markup in there ("`<p>`", "`<ul>`", "`<li>`", etc)?

Comment: @Frederic - I'm using Firefox, I've tried it on Chrome and IE and the same's happening. It could be that Edit Desc is powered by a ckeditor that's changing the value after loading somehow.

Comment: @Pointy - ckeditor.. So it is full of markup yeah, i think it might be the issue too. Would have probably have been worth mentioning that..

Comment: @Alex, ckeditor is probably the culprit indeed...

Comment: @Alex Still not late, you should edit this into your question.

Comment: @Alex Just one idea: are you sure you run the first `serialize` **after** CKEditor was initialized?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments on your original post, I'm assuming you're using CKEditor and in your jQuery ready function (or somewhere after your document loaded) you replace a textarea with an editor instance. CKEditor, like most WYSIWYG editors likes to reformat the text that you pass to it, making it valid markup, replacing special characters with HTML entities, wrapping your content in a paragraph, etc. This means although you haven't changed anything, the original and the reformatted content can be different.

The initialisation of the editor instance is delayed and probably occurs after you've serialised your form. Even so, CKEditor is not strongly linked with the (now hidden) textarea that it's been created from, you need to call the editor's updateElement function to flush all changes. It usually does it automatically on form submit, that's why you're getting the reformatted content in your submit handler.

So you just need to make sure you call the updateElement function before you're serialising the first time, for which the best place is after the editor has loaded. Luckily there is an event for that, assuming the following HTML markup:

```
<form id="myForm">
   <textarea name="test" id="myEditor">My random text</textarea>
</form>
```

jQuery ready function:

```
$(function(){
   function SerializeForm(){
      // Make sure we have the reformatted version of the initial content in the textarea
      CKEDITOR.instances.myEditor.updateElement();

      // Save the initial serialization
      form_data.edit_initial = $('#myForm').serialize();
   }

   // You might as well leave it here in case CKEditor fails to load
   form_data.edit_initial = $('#myForm').serialize();

   // Create editor instance    
   CKEDITOR.replace('myEditor');

   // Tap into CKEditor's ready event to serialize the initial form state
   CKEDITOR.instances.myEditor.on("instanceReady", SerializeForm);
});
```

Comment: i tried this code.but it throws some ajax error ("500,internal server error")

Comment: @SivaRajini: The above code is entirely client-side JavaScript, it could only cause JS errors. Error 500 is probably caused by an error in your server-side program.

Comment: Yes you are right!!!i got it some validation problem in server side!!! Thank you very much for your prompt response

Comment: 8 years later still very usefull and true..you see quite not much progress on CK Editor in such ajax issues...

Answer (score 13):

Thanks! I've had problems long time now with CKEditor textarea. I couldn't get changed value without a submit in cakephp.

But now all works. I had to call `updateElement` before `serialize` like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.SurveyBody.updateElement();
var formData = $("#surveyForm").serialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using several instances of CK Editor at a time, you can use a more generic method before serializing your form:

```
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
    };
    var data = $('#my-form').serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

The values are URI-encoded because ".serialize()" is intended to be used when preparing HTTP parameters for transmission.

You can gather the values of all the form elements into a big string by just iterating over all the `<input>` elements (and `<select>` and `<textarea>` too, if applicable).  Radio buttons get a little tricky but it's still a pretty minor effort.

Comment: Any idea why they're different though?

Comment: You're absolutely certain that calling ".serialize()" twice on the same form, with the same field values, produces different results()?  That seems pretty far-fetched.

Comment: check the sample data in the question, an apostrophe on one is replaced by the html code (or whatever encoding it is) for it on the other

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> The .serialize() method creates a text
>   string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation.

That is why you have those percentages and numbers. Though it should return the same value no matter how many times you call it, so I'm sure you're doing something to your form between the two calls.

You could use a different approach like

```
var form_changed=false;

$('#edit-job-form :input').change(function () {
    form_changed=true;
});
```

[jQuery :input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: My issue there is that if I change a field, name for example, from Alex to Mark and then back to Alex, with your way it would think it's changed but really the data is the same, it's a compromise I might have to make.

Comment: Sounds like acceptable behaviour to me. Add and then delete a space in any text editor (at least the ones I use), they will say that it was changed.